# Is there R function to combine many data frames

Tags: r

I have a sample of 2 datasets (c and d). I have combines them using combine command

```
 c <- data.frame(x=c("a","b"),y=c("c","d"))
 d <- data.frame(x=c("f","g"),y=c("h","e"))
 library(gdata)
 combine(c,d)
  x y source
1 a c      c
2 b d      c
3 f h      d
4 g e      d
```

Well. Suppose I have 100 dataframe like c,d,e,f..... and so on(with same columns). Is there a way to combine all these in a quick way. Or else i need to call below command

```
 combine(c,d,e,f........) 

 df <- read.csv(file.choose())
 combine(df)
```

And the above is very time consuming. Is there a alternate to combine all dataframes easily

Comment: how will you specify the dataframes if not by name? can you put them in a list?

Comment: So you must have their names in a list someplace, right?

Comment: Yes, I have them in csv file. like "A" is the column name and under this, I have c,d,e,f and so on. Can I call csv file with "df" and then use combine. LIke the once I have edited in question. Please check. But I checked and it did not work

Comment: Do you have the actual data frames also in a list? Or can you put them in a list easily, for example with list.files() in case they are stored in separate csv files?

Comment: they are not in seperate csv files. They are in R only. They all are dataframe only. I have around 100 dataframe like c and d (till n). I need to combine them easily rather than giving combine(c,d,e,f.................................n)

Comment: "combine" doesn't seem to be the best word for "bind", as in `rbind`, which seems to be the solution sought by the OP. However, I was hesitant to edit it, as it could be the word a potential OP searches for. Opinions?

Comment: I understand that your data is not in separate csv files, but where is your data before you read it into R? Or do you generate the dataframes with some other method within R (like random numbers etc.)?

Comment: Jana P what TimTeaFan is asking is how 100 dataframes got into R. You probably either created them manually or used `assign`, neither of which is a good idea. It's better to store multiple dataframes in objects such as lists, which allows them to be programmatically manipulated. For instance, if they are from CSVs you can run `df_list <- lapply(list.files(pattern = "*\\.csv"), read.csv)` to import all CSVs in your working directory into a list. Combining them can then be as easy as `do.call("cbind", df_list)`, assuming the dataframes have the same number of rows.

Answer (score 3):

You can list all file you want to read in a directory using this:

```
listoffiles <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
```

Then loop over all files and `assign` it a variable name with `df_`.

```
for(i in 1:length(listoffiles)) {
   assign(paste0("df_", i), read.csv2(listoffiles[i]))
}
```

Then search for all files in your global environment.
Then you can specify a search pattern which would be `"df_"` and would result in a list of data.frames.

```
dflist <- mget(ls(.GlobalEnv, pattern = "df_"), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Then use `rbindlist` from `data.table` to combine your data.frames.

```
> data.table::rbindlist(dflist)
   x y
1: a c
2: b d
3: f h
4: g e
```

Comment: Thanks. But here again i need to change the names of it and make it start with df_. Time consuming :)

Comment: Thanks. But again, my dataframes(c,d,r,f........n) are not in my directory. I cannot read them. All of them are in R only.

Comment: Press Ctrl + Alt + Shift + M to rename multiple lines at once. Well preparing and naming data.frames is part of the preprocessing workflow...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, then the OP has the names of the dataframes in a character vector, but the dataframes themselves are single objects in the global environment . In that case I would suggest the following.

Let this be the data and the character vector:

```
 c <- data.frame(x=c("a","b"),y=c("c","d"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 d <- data.frame(x=c("f","g"),y=c("h","e"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 e <- data.frame(x=c("x","y"),y=c("o","p"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 df_names <- c("c", "d","e")
```

Then dplyr::bind_rows with c(mget(...)) should do the the job.

```
library(dplyr)   
bind_rows(c(mget(df_names)), .id = "source") 

> source x y
1      c a c
2      c b d
3      d f h
4      d g e
5      e x o
6      e y p
```